# Clearing session, flushing, refreshing, after hibernate bulk updates?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, orm

As we know, when doing a bulk update to the DB with hibernate (even in HQL), the changes made are not replicated to the entities stored in the current session.

So i may call session.refresh to load the modifications to my session entities.

We often call flush for sending our modifications to the DB, but the documentation say it "synchronize" the session and the db...

Does that mean that flush will be able to set the good new db value to my session entity? Or flush will eventually erase my new db value with the old one stored in the entity?
(Btw if hibernate's behaviour is the 1st one, how does it detect which one is the "good value"?).

If i can't use flush on such a case, it is a good practice to clear the session after each bulk update so that we are sure to have good values in our session?

Comment: "As we know, when doing a bulk update to the DB with hibernate (even in HQL), the changes made are not replicated to the entities stored in the current session." I did not quite understand what you meant here. Are you updating the DB in one `Session` and wanting to get the update reflected in the objects in the first-level cache of another `Session`?

Comment: No i am doing a "update xxxEntity set yyy=zzz" request and when doing that, the xxxEntity objects that are already on your session cache do not have yet the yyy=zzz value set unless you call a session.refresh on these entities.

Comment: I C. This is a guess, but I don't think `flush` over-writes the changes you make to the DB with the bulk update. When Hibernate loads an entity, it creates two objects - one it keeps to itself and one it hands out to you. When a `session` is `flush`ed, Hibernate compares the state of the copy it (i.e. the "original") has and the copy it gave to you; it issues SQL based on differences, if any. I have over-simplified it, but this is essentially the mental model I have. So my guess is that Hibernate will not issue any SQL for your entities because it detects no changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All `flush` will do is sending previously cached SQL statements to the database. It will not change your objects that are already in session. In a way it does opposite to what you need. SQL statements from flush may, potentially, override your bulk update changes. What you probably want to do is `flush()` and then `clear()` before your update. Or, if you don't want to clear the entire cache, `evict()`. I never tried `refresh()` but it seems that it will also work.

Comment: Flush and clearing before the update seems nice to me, better that flushing and clearing after to avoid my bulk update to be erased by non flushed yet entities...

Comment: why SQL statements from flush may, potentially, override your bulk update changes?