# Evaluate whether an entity satisfies a "where" HQL query

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm writing a bit of tooling so that my app defaults to bulk HQL deletes where possible. This is to squeeze a bit more performance out of my app. However this can potentially leave the data in the session stale because [HQL deletes by-pass the session level cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757244/clearing-session-flushing-refreshing-after-hibernate-bulk-updates).

I could evict the all instances of the entity class being deleted from the session level cache. This may cause problems the other way around because entities added to the session may be evicted before they have been flushed to the database.

What I would like to be able to do is evaluate whether a particular entity satisfies the HQL "where" clause in the delete statement. If it does, then I can evict it from the session level cache, knowing that it will have been deleted from the database by the bulk HQL delete.

I can't see any obvious methods to allow me do do this. I could crack open the [HqlParser](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/hql/internal/ast/HqlParser.html) and do this myself but I suspect heading down this route will become a hefty coding task.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you use delete or update query instant of update() method.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow your point. I plan to use the delete query, but that may leave the data in the session level cache in an invalid state. Could you explain any further please?

Comment: when your using delete query i think hibernate will not load full object to session.

Comment: That's correct. However a select, delete and save could cause a NonUniqueObjectException if the natural key is used as the identifier:

// fills the session
session.createQuery("from Employee").list()                
// deletes data from database but session untouched
session.createQuery("delete from Employee").executeUpdate()
// boom: NonUniqueObjectException 
session.save(new Employee())

While it seems obvious to not delete and insert, but update instead, there is a lot of legacy code that would need to be refactored.