# Hibernate pagination or batch processing

Tags: oracle, hibernate

**Question:** How can I process (read in) batches of records 1000 at a time and ensure that only the current batch of 1000 records is in memory? Assume my primary key is called '`ID`' and my table is called `Customer`.

**Background:** This is not for user pagination, it is for compiling statistics about my table. I have limited memory available, therefore I want to read my records in batches of 1000 records at a time. I am only reading in records, they will not be modified. I have read that `StatelessSession` is good for this kind of thing and I've heard about people using `ScrollableResults`.

**What I have tried:** Currently I am working on a custom made solution where I implemented Iterable and basically did the pagination by using `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults`. This seems to be very slow for me but it allows me to get 1000 records at a time. I would like to know how I can do this more efficiently, perhaps with something like `ScrollableResults`. I'm not yet sure why my current method is so slow; I'm ordering by ID but ID is the primary key so the table should already be indexed that way.

As you might be able to tell, I keep reading bits and pieces about how to do this. If anyone can provide me a complete way to do this it would be greatly appreciated. I do know that you have to set `FORWARD_ONLY` on `ScrollableResults` and that calling `evict(entity)` will take an entity out of memory (unless you're doing second level caching, which I do not yet know how to check if I am or not). However I don't see any methods in the JavaDoc to read in say, 1000 records at a time. I want a balance between my lack of available memory and my slow network performance, so sending records over the network one at a time really isn't an option here. I am using Criteria API where possible. Thanks for any detailed replies.

Comment: side note, if anyone can point out the appropriate terminology for 'scrolling through records X at a time' in the comments, that'd be appreciated. I thought it was called batch processing but the Hibernate docs only mention updating & deleting in their batch section...

Comment: It is a form of batch processing / pagination, it's just that it probably isn't a very common request. I had a need to do this and ended up just fetching all the PKs in memory and doing a whole lot of `where Id in (...)` queries.

Comment: Also, just because your table is indexed by PK doesn't necessarily mean the records are internally ordered by PK. The table might use an extensible-hashing index. Even if that doesn't sound likely, B+-trees seem to be more common. Also, the query might filter using on a different index than the PK one at some point, which means it'd still need to re-sort the results afterwards. (E.g. if you're selecting records in a date range, they would be retrieved from the table ordered by date.) An EXPLAIN should clear this up.

Comment: @millimoose The oracle documentation seems to say otherwise (about the PK always being index)

Comment: I'm not saying the PK is not being indexed. I'm saying it might not be the index that's accessed first when a query is being executed. (Which would determine in which order the elements are in before ordering is applied.)

Comment: @millimoose Gotcha. The other field in my where clause isn't indexed though, and I'm ordering by ID as I said, and ID is the PK. Why would it do anything other than use the already-sorted ID field? Not saying you're wrong, in fact you seem to be right judging by the slowness, I just don't get how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Load entities as read-only.

   For HQL

   ```
   Query.setReadOnly( true );
   ```

   For Criteria

   ```
   Criteria.setReadOnly( true );
   ```

   http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/readonly.html#readonly-api-querycriteria

   Stateless session quite different with State-Session.

   > Operations performed using a stateless session never cascade to associated instances. Collections are ignored by a stateless session

   http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession
2. Use flash() and clear() to clean up session cache.

   session.flush();

   session.clear();

   [Question about Hibernate session.flush()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274958/question-about-hibernate-session-flush)
3. ScrollableResults should works that you expect.

   Do not forget that each item that you loaded takes memory space unless you evict or clear and need to check it really works well.

   ScrollableResults in Mysql J/Connecotr works fake, it loads entire rows, but I think oracle connector works fine.

   [Using Hibernate's ScrollableResults to slowly read 90 million records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826319/using-hibernates-scrollableresults-to-slowly-read-90-million-records)

   If you find alternatives, you may consider to use this way

   ```
   1. Select PrimaryKey of every rows that you will process 
   2. Chopping them into PK chunk
   3. iterate -
      select rows by PK chunk (using in-query) 
      process them what you want
   ```

Comment: `@Transactional` is Spring specific, which isn't mentioned anywhere in post/tags.

Comment: What does loading entities as read only solve? How can I grab 1000 records at a time? Is it setting the fetch size? The fetch size section of the hibernate docs refers to associations not anything else. Or is it setFirstResult and setMaxResults? If it is then why would I use a ScrollableResults with it?

Answer (score 1):

May useing of **ROWNUM** feature of oracle will hepl you. 
Lets say we need to fetch 1000 rows(*pagesize*) of table CUSTOMERS and we need to fetch second page(*pageNumber*)

Creating and Calling some query like this may be the answer

```
select * from 
  (select rownum row_number,customers.* from Customer 
   where rownum <= pagesize*pageNumber order by ID)
where row_number >= (pagesize -1)*pageNumber
```

Comment: If rows are added during this process, that could throw off rownum, correct?  Something to be aware of.

Comment: if its for some of your entities you may use Native Query, else must be implemented in your base DataAcess layer implementation.

Comment: @Marvo: No, Oracle manages the query result not to be interfering with currently added rows --- plz see "Statement-Level Read Consistency" at http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10743/consist.htm

Comment: @M.Heydari The title says it all. "Statement-Level". Fetching subsequent chunks would occur in separate statements. (Of course it's possible transactions would handle this well.)

Comment: So the correctness of each query will be guaranteed by isolation level and correctness of overall statements when will be guaranteed when using order by ID

Comment: @M.Heydari it would maintain statement level read consistency during that query.  But he's got umpteen number of queries to perform, 1000 records at a time.  If you have ten records, process the first three in this manner, then insert a record that has an ID that would make it the second record, you would then process the third record for a second time on the next query.  Unless he wraps the entire thing in a transaction, which might be prohibitive.

Comment: It's possible that he's not performing updates to this data, in which case the point is moot.

Comment: if the ID is not a sequence ... so there must be a TimeStamp field and the ORDER By must be based on it, .... is ID not a sequence?

Comment: Wouldn't matter if records can be deleted.

Comment: Since the pivot element (id or time stamp) is incremental, No ... if record with id (1,2,3) exists so removing 2 wont change the ORDER BY result