# spring-hibernate transaction- changes not reflecting?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring and Hibernate. I have a method annotated with `@Transactional`. This method has two database calls. One call would update the data in the table and the other call would retrieve some data from the same table based on the first call's updated data. 
The problem is first call's database change is not reflected immediately. Change is reflected after the flow comes out of the method which is annotated with `@Transactional`. I still tried calling `session.flush()` but no use. Please suggest me.

```
@Transactional
public void method1(){
dao.updateM1();
dao.getData();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you elaborate on your scenario? For example: what propagation level did you declare for **updateM1** and **getData** methods?

In case, you didn't describe Transactional for **updateM1**, and **getData** methods, the problem is both methods are in one same transaction. As a result, Hibernate won't update the data until the transaction is committed. To solve that problem, you just describe the transaction for **updateM1** as below:

```
@Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRE_NEW)
public E updateM1() {}
```

With that, a new transaction will be created every time **updateM1** is called. When the updateM1 is finished, that new transaction is committed and all changes will be persisted in the database.

About session.flush not working, here is one clear answer: [Question about Hibernate session.flush()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274958/question-about-hibernate-session-flush)

Answer (score 1):

In my knowledge After completion of transaction method only the changes will reflect in the database.

But here you are calling before completion of the method.So you are not getting the updated result.

Comment: @user755806 did you understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when you you use `@Transaction` annotation on method. Any database change in the logic of your body should be committed at the end of method call.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it important what's updated in the database?

Think rather about the entities' state in the persistence context.

Perhaps you should try `session.refresh()` to refresh the entities' state but your code is not enough detailed to see why it doesn't work.

How are your `update` and `get` methods implemented?

Answer (score 0):

It's not suggest calling `session.flush()` manually, I think you can separate the two calls with dao to two different service method, make them have different transaction propagation attributes,

```
@Transactional
public void method1(){
    this.updateM1Service();
    this.getDataService();
}

@Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRE_NEW)
public void updateM1Service(){
    dao.updateM1();
}

@Transactional
public void getDataService(){
    dao.getData();
}
```