# Changes made in a @Transactional method are not reflected to the Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have the following method in my Service Layer, which

1. Retrieves an entity by ID
2. Executes an update to the entity
3. Retrieves and returns the same entity

   ```
   @Transactional
   @Override
   public Order acceptOrder(long orderId){
       Order Order = getOrderById(orderId);                                  // 1
       orderDao.updateOrderStatus(OrderStatus.PENDING_COMPLETION, orderId);  // 2
       return getOrderById(orderId);                                         // 3
   }
   ```

   The service's method `getOrderById`

   ```
   @Override
   public Order getOrderById(long id) {
       return orderDao.get(Order.class, id);
   }
   ```

And the DAO's method `updateOrderStatus`

```
    @Override
    public int updateOrderStatus(AppEnums.OrderStatus status, long orderId) {
        String query = "update Order set orderStatus=:status where id=:orderId";
        Query q = getHibernateSession().createQuery(query);
        q.setParameter("status", status);
        q.setParameter("orderId", orderId);
        return q.executeUpdate();
    }
```

When the method executes the DB is updated successfully but the returned entity's status does **not** reflect the updated status value. Shouldn't changes made in the same transaction be visible by default?

Comment: No. Because you aren't updating the entity but using a query to do changes in the database. The `Order` you get is the one already in the first level cache and that hasn't been refreshed. You shouldn't be doing things like that you should update your `Order` and store the order, don't use queries to do things like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may,

### Update your entity and save it

(As M.Deinum suggested in the comments)

```
order.setOrderStatus(OrderStatus.PENDING_COMPLETION);  //2
return salesOrderDao.saveOrUpdate(order);              //3
```

### Commit your transaction once it's updated

```
@Transactional
@Override
public Order acceptOrder(long orderId){
    Order order = getOrderById(orderId);                                  // 1
    orderDao.updateOrderStatus(OrderStatus.PENDING_COMPLETION, orderId);  // 2
    //commit the transaction                                              // 3
    return getOrderById(orderId);                                         // 4
}
```

Note: You will need to access the transaction someway.

### Remove the instance from the session cache

You can do this using [Session.evict](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict(java.lang.Object))

```
orderDao.updateOrderStatus(OrderStatus.PENDING_COMPLETION, orderId);  //2
hibernateSession.evict(order);                                        //3
return getOrderById(orderId);                                         //4
```

Note: You will need to access the HibernateSession

But you can do something like this mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16464724/1793718),

```
@Transactional
public void method1(){
    this.updateM1Service();
    this.getDataService();
}

@Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void updateM1Service(){
    dao.updateM1();
}

@Transactional
public void getDataService(){
    dao.getData();
}
```

Comment: Yes I guess that would work, but shouldn't the changes be visible since the update takes place in the same @Transactional method?

Comment: No, hibernate won't commit the transaction. So it is not saved in the DB until the transaction in completed. You are calling the `getOrderById` before the transaction is over. You can do something like a nested transaction using `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`. Like the one mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16464724/1793718).