# Spring @Transactional does not update data in session

Tags: spring, hibernate, ubuntu

I have a very strange problem on a Spring/Hibernate server. My collegue working on a Mac doesn't experience the same problem, but I'm on Ubuntu and something weird is happening.

This probably relates to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200369/changes-made-in-a-transactional-method-are-not-reflected-to-the-entity) but the suggested fixes don't seem to work for me.

I have a Job that picks up messages from Amazon SQS and completes that job.

I had to make the class @Transactional to get around

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: 
could not initialize proxy [co.example.model.Scene#5] 
- no Session
```

At the end of this job some data is saved

```
        scene.setStatus(4);
        sceneRepository.save(scene);

        log.info("sceneProcessingComplete" +  scene.getId() + " " + scene.getStatus());
```

This data is persisted to the database as expected. However this log returns the previous value.

Subsequent to this a call is made to the server from the client which also returns the previous value, even tho I can see it's 4 in the DB.

It's like the @Transactional doesn't update the entity in session?

```
@Service
@Scope("singleton")
@EnableAsync
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Slf4j
public class ProcessVideoQueueJob extends AmazonService {


@Scheduled(fixedRate = 50000)
public void start() {

    this.initSQSClient(); 
    this.initS3Client();
    this.checkProcessingQueue();

} 

public void checkProcessingQueue(){
  ....
complete(processingJob, jobStatusNotification);

public void complete(ProcessingJob processingJob,
JobStatusNotification jobStatusNotification ){
    try{
     Scene scene = sceneRepository.getOne(sceneId);
      ....
      scene.setStatus(4);
        sceneRepository.save(scene);

        log.info("sceneProcessingComplete" +  scene.getId() + " " + scene.getStatus());


        return;
```

Adding this return meant that first log is now showing a 4.

A subsequent call to the api

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/scene/{id}", method = GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getScene(@PathVariable("id") long id)  {
    JwtUser jwtUser = this.getJwtUser();

    Scene scene = sceneService.getScene(id);

    if(!canAccess(jwtUser, scene)){
        return this.getUnauthorizedResponse();
    }

    log.info("Get Scene: " + scene.getId() + "  status:" + scene.getStatus());

    return ResponseEntity.ok(scene);
}
```

Returns a 2.  In the databse it is a 4.

SceneRepository.java

```
public interface SceneRepository extends JpaRepository<Scene, Long> {


    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value ="UPDATE example.scene SET video_id = :video_id, status = :status WHERE id = :id",nativeQuery=true)
    void updateSceneVideoId(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("video_id") Long videoId, @Param("status") int status );

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value ="UPDATE example.scene SET image_id = :image_id, status = :status WHERE id = :id",nativeQuery=true)
    void updateSceneImageId(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("image_id") Long imageId, @Param("status") int status );


}
```

Comment: How is scene entity in the method complete()  declared? Is SceneRepository  a spring-data repository?

Comment: complete is declared when the job is picked up in checkProcessingQueue(). SceneRepository is a JPA.

Comment: Is Scene object entity builded with own constructor? Can you post SceneRepository code?

Comment: Thanks @MichelFoucault have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to move the `start` method in another class which calls `complete()` method of `ProcessVideoQueueJob` class. For example you can create a new class `ProcessVideoQueueJobStarter` 
Below is the code snippet.

```
public class ProcessVideoQueueJobStarter extends AmazonService {

    @Autowired
    ProcessVideoQueueJob pj;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 50000)
    public void start() {

        this.initSQSClient(); 
        this.initS3Client();
        this.checkProcessingQueue();

    } 

        public void checkProcessingQueue(){
          ....
        pj.complete(processingJob, jobStatusNotification);

    *
```

Comment: I can. Which part should be @transactional?

Comment: ProcessVideoQueueJob class which contains complete() method with the saving in the db

Comment: yes I did I thought I replied? ... anyway, didn't make any difference, but the problem isn't happening on my collegues machine or production server so we're leaving it for now. Thanks for your help!