# Why is it necessary to call session.flush() after session.delete() in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

The problem is following code snippet doesn't delete the record in DB.

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
...
...
void deleteForm() {
   Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
   FormDO formDO = new FormDO();
   formDO.setId(formId);
   session.delete(formDO); // No delete SQL query is getting fired.
```

However, if I call **session.flush()** after delete, it works perfectly. Please note, I am NOT using any Transaction.

In JavaDoc of Session class the description of delete method is:

> Remove a persistent instance from the datastore. The argument may be an instance associated with the receiving Session or **a transient instance** with an identifier associated with existing persistent state.

And I have seen many code snippets online which shows that it is not necessary to call flush() after delete(). Similar question was raised in other forum [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=925663) but it remained unanswered.

Also, session.save works fine without session.flush.

I am using Hibernate 4.2.16 + Spring 4.0.9 + JPA 1.0 annotations. Following are the source files for further reference,

**FormDO.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="form")
    public class FormDO {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    Integer id;
    @Column(name="name")
    String name;
    ...
    ...
```

**Spring Configuration File**

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tempdb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="****" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.test.FormDO</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**FormDAO.java**

```
@Named
public class FormDAO {
    @Inject
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public boolean deleteForm(Integer formId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        FormDO formDO = new FormDO();
        formDO.setId(formId);
        session.delete(formDO);
        session.flush(); // If this line is commented, record DOES NOT get deleted
        return true;
    }
    public boolean saveForm(FormDO formDO) { 
       Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
       session.save(formDO); // Save doesn't require session.flush
       return true;
    }
    ...
    ...
```

**UPDATE:**

My dilemma was largely due to the inconsistency.. session.save was inserting the record immediately but session.delete doesn't reflect unless flush() was called explicitly. But when I refer the [Flushing the Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing) link posted by Afsun, my doubts were cleared by reading following line,

> An exception is that objects using native ID generation are inserted when they are saved.

I really appreciate the answers posted by everyone as almost all of them were pointing to the right direction but Afsun clears my doubt totally. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your work with database via Hibernate you are using `Hibernate session`. `Hibernate sessions` flushed to the database by following three situations.

1. `commit()`- When you commit a transaction
2. Before you run a query
3. When you call `session.flush()`

Here the most important is second. After every query does not `Hibernate session` flush database. If we run `Native SQL Query` via Hibernate,Hibernate does not know to flush the session or also if run `HQL` also Hibernate does not know to flush session. The call to flush will synchronise the session state with the database. 
See the following:
[Hibernate flush before delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274958/question-about-hibernate-session-flush) and [Flushing the Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing)

Answer (score 7):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush()) for the Hibernate Session class:

> Flushing is the process of synchronizing the underlying persistent store with persistable state held in memory.

When you make your call to `session.delete()` you tell Hibernate to remove the entity from being managed.  However, the corresponding record will still exist in the underlying database.  You need to make the call to `session.flush()` in order to sync the database with the Hibernate session.  Note that if your program were to end without your calling `session.flush()` then next time you start up the app again the entity in question would reappear.

Answer (score 2):

[flush()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html) This method forces current session to flush. Must be called at the end of a unit of work, before commiting the transaction and closing the session (depending on flush-mode, Transaction.commit() calls this method).
Flushing is the process of synchronizing the underlying persistent store with persistable state held in memory.

Therefore **it is necessary flush the session when you call delete or else the deleted record will still exist in the underlying database.** Also you are not closing the sessions you are opening.This may be issue when you start using pooling mechanism. The best practice is in most cases session-per-request.Closing a session will always flush al work to the database. 

Also you need to flush in batch processing otherwise it may give OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about session.close. As I have just begun writing this new code, I missed it. But anyway I would like to disagree with you when you say, 'Closing a session will always flush all work to the database.' I tried and it did not. Please refer below URL,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931162/will-hibernate-flush-my-updated-persistent-object-when-calling-session-close-w

Comment: Thanks my assumption about close() calling flush() was wrong and yes its good practice to close a session.